# Bumping Topics if Nobody has Replied to Them

Tags: support

I don't want to be seen to break the rules here are Stack Overflow which brings me to my question...

Nobody has replied to a question that I have asked and now the question is many pages down. Is bumping my own questions allowed so that they appear at the top? And if so, what is the time frame I should wait to do so?

Comment: do it after you get the [Tumbleweed bage ;)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) and do it by offering a bounty rather than just "bumping" it

Comment: If you can see a clear way to improve your post with an edit, you're more than welcome to at any time. Just don't do it repeatedly with minor edits just for the sake of bumping.

Comment: @mehow - OP has 6 rep. How exactly are they supposed to offer a bounty?

Comment: @Oded gain rep by suggesting edits :)

Comment: Don't try for bounty, too much community effort (4 reviewers per edit) will be required for you to reach enough rep to offer bounty. Should look again at your post, if it didn't get an answer, then maybe some more info/details should be added to the question and also focus on better formatting. This will help increase the clarity of the question, and increase probability of getting an answer. These kind of substantial edits add a lot of value to your posts.

Answer (score 2):

You should wait at least a few hours. And even then, be *very* careful about bumping a question that got ignored the first time around - whatever you do, don't bump it *as-is*...

It's possible your question was ignored the first time around because you were just unlucky and no one saw it. But it's *far* more likely that it just didn't look interesting. **So fix that!**

- Make sure your title is a complete, concise summary of the problem you're trying to solve. Most people seeing your question will read *nothing else* - so make it count!
- Make sure your question starts with a clear statement of the problem you're trying to solve and why you're trying to solve it. Aim for a short (2-3 line) paragraph - a little more is ok, but avoid it if you can. This is your second chance to catch the attention of anyone who thought your title looked interesting, so whatever you do don't waste this space on fluff like *"Hi folks"* or *"Greetings, fellow humans from the planet earth on which I was born and definitely not hatched from an egg fallen to ground from parts unknown!"*
- *Then* include the details on what you've tried so far to solve your problem, any relevant code, test results, etc.
- Oh, and make sure your question has tags that reflect the topics it pertains to, *and none that are superfluous*. You want anyone likely to have an interest in your question's subject matter to see it in their feed, but the *last* thing you want is to catch the attention of someone who is trying to avoid these same topics!

Such an edit will automatically bump your question back to the front page, and if you made the most of it will garner some positive attention.

Note that the system will *automatically* bump old, unanswered questions back to the front page at random.